# Replace pandas column values with array

Tags: python, pandas

I have an array:

```
([ 137.55021238,  125.30017675,  130.20181675,  109.47348838])
```

**I need the array values to replace the b column, with the index number remaining the same:**

```
Index    a         b         
0       0.671399 Nan
35      0.446172 Nan
63      0.614758 Nan
72      0.634448 Nan
```

I tried to use replace but it didn't work. Is there another way of doing this without turning array into a dataframe and merging?

Comment: `df['b'] = [ 137.55021238, 125.30017675, 130.20181675, 109.47348838]` why won't this work?

Comment: oh shoot. I overestimated the problem that had such a simple solution. Thank you @coldspeed. Should I erase this question that I posted?

Comment: I think this might be a duplicate, but it's okay to leave it be.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
vals = [137.55021238, 125.30017675, 130.20181675, 109.47348838]
```

---

**Option 1**
Direct assignment.

```
df['b'] = vals
print(df)
              a           b
Index
0      0.671399  137.550212
35     0.446172  125.300177
63     0.614758  130.201817
72     0.634448  109.473488
```

---

**Option 2**
*`df.assign`*

```
df = df.assign(b=vals)
print(df)
              a           b
Index
0      0.671399  137.550212
35     0.446172  125.300177
63     0.614758  130.201817
72     0.634448  109.473488
```

---

**Option 3**
*`df.fillna`*

```
df.b = df.b.fillna(pd.Series(vals, index=df.index))
print(df)
              a           b
Index
0      0.671399  137.550212
35     0.446172  125.300177
63     0.614758  130.201817
72     0.634448  109.473488
```

If your values are `Nan` (string) instead of `NaN` (float), you can convert it, using `df.replace`:

```
df = df.replace('Nan', np.nan)
```

Comment: thank you. I'll accept your answer in 10 minutes @coldspeed

Comment: @piRSquared Thought of you when writing the assign :)